# How to read current week number from excel sheet?

Tags: python-2.7, xlrd

In excel contains details of so many weeks,I need to print only current week number from excel sheet,if only current week conditions matches it should print that

piece of code for that condition but it showing error:

```
 rec_date = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(rec, inputfp.datemode)).isocalendar()[1]
 if rec_date == date.today().isocalendar()[1]:
    print '\n',rec_date 
    print str(out[rec])
```

Showing error:

```
if rec_date == date.today():
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'today'
```

Comment: What error is thrown? Please post the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

So I presume you do not import `date` from `datetime` but just import `datetime`. So

```
if rec_date == datetime.date.today()
```

shall work. Or `from datetime import date`